# Undefined type constructor "Int" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This work ok:

```
increment :: Int -> Int
increment i = i + 1
```

But why this not:

```
module MyFile where
import Prelude (Show)

increment :: Int -> Int
increment i = i + 1
```

Hugs say: Undefined type constructor "Int"

I suppose i need to import more things.

Comment: You don't have to explicitly import Prelude at all, you know. Those functions and types are imported by default unless overridden. Unless you're writing functions with names that conflict with those in Prelude, you can just use them without an import statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Int` is defined in `Prelude`, but in your case you only import `Show` from Prelude. Therefore, the definition of `Int` cannot be found. To rectify, modify as `import Prelude (Show, Int, (+))`.

Comment: Remark: Edit notes should be put in the edit summary, not in the actual answer.

Comment: @Zeta: Thanks for the heads up. Will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

In many Haskell programs, you want to leave the Prelude out of your imports and just let it be imported automatically.

In almost all the rest, you want to import *most* of the Prelude, but leave some pieces out. This can be done using, e.g.,

```
import Prelude hiding (head, tail, (++))
```

In some cases, that will be accompanied by an import to get access to the hidden parts:

```
import qualified Prelude as P
```

In virtually all remaining cases, you will be using some alternative prelude *instead* of the standard one.  The only times I can imagine writing anything that doesn't import most of some prelude are when actually implementing the base modules for a Haskell system, or writing an alternative prelude.